# Table design in a OLTP database

Tags: sql-server, database-design

A debate has stared at work regards a table design and auditing changes. We have a stock table that contains trucks we sell. The table has columns like mileage, location, price and stockdate to name just a few.

The databases is OLTP so quite a few reads and updates when change happens to an items of stock.

I'm happy to leave the table alone and have a shadow table auditing any inserts and updates. However, its been suggested to move most of the stock columns into separate table and to make these tables into slow moving dimensions

Personally I prefer all the data in one row. It seems a lot of hassle to join on 10 tables to bring back one stock record. And the updates will be pain because you'd have to check if each property has changed its value and do an insert if it has and update the last properties entries End Date. This can't be good for performance, can it?

Wouldn't it be better if you wanted to that level of auditing to leave the table alone and move the data to an OLAP?

Comment: I'd first focus on normalizing the table with auditing not driving how you do that.  Once you have it normalized you can create triggers and procedures to wrap your auditing logic and it will all fit together like a puzzle and scale out as time goes on. Typically in OLTP you don't demoralize right off the bat unless you have some edge case to do so.  Have your ran into performance problems with a normalized design, no? then keep it normalized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in denormalizing your table just for auditing purposes.

You might want to look into change data capture to see if it solves your issue without further serious changes:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx